# What's the difference between a 'Sourcer' and a 'Recruiter'?

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns, business-language

In HR terms, what's the difference between a 'Sourcer' and a 'Recruiter'? Why is one preferred over the other?

Comment: Question originally asked at focus.com

Answer (score 1):

A sourcer is someone who collects a list of names and resumes from the internet.

A recruiter is someone who actually talks to the candidates after filtering the info gathered by sourcers.

Normally a recruiter will be a sourcer at the same time or was previously a sourcer.

Answer (score 1):

A sourcer is someone who gathers potential candidates for a recruiter.

A recruiter takes the information provided by a sourcer and attempts to persuade or convince the potential candidates to join, or take a position, whatever the case may be.